# preserve seconds when saving excel to csv/txt

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export-to-csv

When I am saving an exported Excel file as a CSV or text file, the seconds are lost  in `DateTime` data . For example, if `7/10/2019  2:01:39 PM` is shown in Excel, and I save it as a CSV, when I open the CSV, I am  seeing `7/10/2019  2:01:00 PM`.

I am using `Office.Interop.Excel` to save an opened Excel file to CSV. And then opening the CSV file.

This behavior is same if I save Excel file as a txt and then open txt file.

How can I preserve seconds when I save an excel file as csv or txt?

Here is what I have so far:

```
excel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;

//for csv save
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(toFile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows); 

//for txt save
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(toFile, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText,
    AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    ConflictResolution: Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);
```

Comment: I can't help much, but it might be useful in troubleshooting to determine if the file is not being saved correctly, or if it is not being re-opened correctly.  In other words, if you open the csv file in a text editor, are the seconds there?  In Excel itself, if you go through that process, the file is saved correctly, and the value is correct when re-opened (although it is formatted as `m/d/yyy hh:mm`)

Comment: One thing that you could always do, but would be annoying, is to serialize the DateTime objects to strings manually and then saving it to a csv file. That way you have control over how it's serialized.

Comment: I tried it using the code you provided and it worked both ways. Can you post more detail with what your inputs and outputs are?

Comment: few of my inputs are `7/10/2019  2:01:39 PM,   7/10/2019  1:12:00 PM,  7/10/2019  12:44:58 PM` and corresponding outputs in csv file are `7/10/2019  2:01:00 PM,   7/10/2019  1:12:00 PM,  7/10/2019  12:44:00 PM`

Comment: @user1207289 I think I was able to reproduce the issue correctly and proposed a solution below

Comment: @ivcubr , yes , I was able to that. I just needed to add this  to the solution `worksheet.Columns["B"].NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";` . I'll upvote for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had  to format column before I save as csv. I just needed to add this

`worksheet.Columns["B"].NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue by following the steps outlined below. My proposed solution is at the end of the answer, but I am adding the steps I used to reproduce the issue for completeness. The examples I used are as follows:

> 7/10/2019 2:01:39 PM
>
> 7/10/2019 1:12:11 PM
>
> 7/10/2019 12:44:58 PM

1. Create new Excel document and add three example dates as shown below. This is using the default date format from pasting the examples provided in the comments above.

[image: Example Excel data]

2. Run the following code to save as a CSV and text file

---

```
_Application excel = (_Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("test.csv", XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("test.txt", XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);
```

3. Output showing the result the OP was getting

[image: Output results]

---

The solution I found was to update the formatting of the cells before exporting. For instance, if all the dates are in the first row, the following will change the formatting to display the date as desired.

```
Range range = excel.Cells[1,1];
range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss";
```

The full solution . Note the call to `SaveAs` will save in the default folder which for me was my documents folder, not the executing directory.

```
_Application excel = (_Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

Range range = excel.Cells[1,1];
range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss";

excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("test.csv", XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("test.txt", XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);
```

Comment: Excel handles CSV in, let's say, not the best manner. It saves what is shown in cells, not the entire cell content (discussed in many places, for example [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1253889-saving-csv-with-time-data-zeroes-the-seconds.html#post5014414) ). For example, if you open a CSV file with seconds in timestamps, Excel shows them without seconds (default date-time format apparently). If you save that file, seconds will be lost. By the way, LibreOffice Calc handles this situation perfectly.